# field collection showing only one value

Tags: theming, entities

I've a field collection called program, in which it have 2 fields date and time.

I've created a tpl file for the field collection and it is rendering the content as well. But the issue is, it is showing the first value entered the number of times field collection has been added.

What am I doing wrong. I've just copied the content in field-collection-item.tpl.php to my tpl.

Comment: How about you move out your custom tpl? Will it fix? If yes, it is really weird

Comment: Provide some code sample